# User-level threads and information available to the kernel

Tags: threads, os-kernel

User-level threads are transparent to the kernel. How is `htop` able to show user-level threads running on my system? I know that those threads are user-level threads because when I press `H` (for toggling display of user level threads), those threads disappear from the list.

The image below shows three user-level threads for Emacs (which is a single threaded application from the kernel's perspective)

[image]